# OutOfRangeError when creating batch from tfrecord file

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm writing a script that saves certain features of my data to tfrecord. The features are numpy arrays (float32). When I read the tfrecord file I get the following error:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 20, current size 0)
 [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
```

I searched a lot, and apparently this error can be caused by different things. So far, I was not able to fix it. I recreated the problem with the following minimal code:

1. saving the toy data:

   ```
   def _bytes_feature(value):
      return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

   writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('stuff.tfrecords')

   for i in range(100):

       seq = np.random.uniform(size=(500,300)).astype(np.float32)
       lbl = np.random.uniform(size=(90,1)).astype(np.float32)

       feature = {'train/lbl': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(lbl.tostring())),
          'train/seq': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(seq.tostring()))}

       example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

       writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

   writer.close()
   sys.stdout.flush()
   ```
2. Reading the data:

   ```
   def read_and_decode_single_example(filename):

       filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=1)   
       reader = tf.TFRecordReader() 
       _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
       f = {'train/lbl': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'train/seq': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}

       features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=f)

       seq = tf.decode_raw(features['train/seq'], tf.float32)
       lbl = tf.decode_raw(features['train/lbl'], tf.float32)

       seq = tf.reshape(seq, [ 500,300 ])
       lbl = tf.reshape(lbl, [ 90,1 ])

       sbatch, lbatch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([seq, lbl],
                                     batch_size= batch_size,
                                     capacity=3*batch_size,
                                     min_after_dequeue=batch_size)

       return sbatch, lbatch 


   sbatch, lbatch = read_and_decode_single_example("stuff.tfrecords" )

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
       threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

       sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
       sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

       s,l = sess.run([sbatch, lbatch])

       coord.request_stop()
       coord.join(threads)
   ```

I'm using Tensorflow-GPU v. 1.4.0.
Here is some error code, that may be informative:

```
Caused by op 'shuffle_batch', defined at:
 File "teststuff.py", line 59, in <module>
sbatch, lbatch = read_and_decode_single_example("stuff.tfrecords" )
 File "teststuff.py", line 54, in read_and_decode_single_example
min_after_dequeue=batch_size)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 1225, in shuffle_batch
name=name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 796, in _shuffle_batch
dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 464, in dequeue_many
self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2418, in _queue_dequeue_many_v2
component_types=component_types, timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
```